# Angular Use Template to Set Environment Variable

Tags: angular, docker

I have several Angular applications which will connect to an API. the API service and applications will all run in several different locations with the API base URL base on the location. Also, these applications will be running inside docker containers

I've read through [How to use the environment for specific HTTP services](https://indepth.dev/posts/1188/how-to-use-the-environment-for-specific-http-services) and I understand using the environment files to set different API base URLs by environment. However, what I would like to do would be to set the URL as a variable in the docker-compose file and use that value to set the API base URL.

So my thought process would be this

docker-compose.yml

```
version '3.7'
services:
    app1: 
        image: app_image1:1.0.0
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        environment:
            API_BASE_URL: http://0.0.0.0/data
```

and then somewhere in the app be able to read and use that value. Maybe in the environment file doing some sort of substitution...

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
  baseUrl: ${API_BASE_URL}
}
```

Is something like that possible? Or do I have to setup an environment file for each location
`environment.prod.loca.ts`, `environment.prod.locb.ts`, etc.?

What is the best approach to handling this?

> EDIT

For clarity both the application and API will be deployed to several different locations. The API will be site specific with the root URL based on the IP address of the server it is deployed to.

This is what I am trying to talk, how can I supply the base URL to the angular application so as to not have to rebuild the application several times just to switch out the API URL?

Comment: Can you run all of the parts behind the same reverse proxy, and use path-only URLs like `/api/path` in your Angular code?  That would avoid needing to rebuild the front-end for each different environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thank you for the comment. It's not the environment I'm concerned about. This application will be deployed to several different servers around the country. Each server will be running a copy of the API, and each API will have a different root URL based on the IP address

Comment: That's the benefit of the reverse-proxy setup, though.  If you can HTTP POST to `/api/path`, it will resolve to the same host as the front-end application, so you can have a fixed URL path in your application code even if you have multiple separated deployments.

Comment: Even though the API and the front end are running in different containers? If so then I may need to give this a look

Comment: Your browser isn't running a container at all and can't use any of the Docker networking features.  With the reverse proxy, your browser application connects to the reverse proxy, which forwards it to one or the other container based on the HTTP path.